# How i can add correctly data to an existing choicefield and save it in database: Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I want to add some choices to an exiting fieldchoice from the database,

I have did that in my **views.py**:

```
    def operation(request):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            form = FormOperation(instance=request.user, )
            var = Metry.objects.filter(user=request.user).last().profile.name
            varr = Metry.objects.filter(user=request.user).last().profile.category
            form.fields['dite'].choices.append((varr, var))  
            print(form.fields['dite'].choices)
        else:
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
               form = FormOperation(request.POST, )
               if form.is_valid():
                  form.save()
        return render(request, 'pages/operation.html',  {'form': form})
```

**models.py:**

```
dite = models.CharField(null = True, max_length=60,choices = CHOICES)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class FormOperation(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Operation
        exclude = ("user",)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

after "append" the choice , As a test I have  did a "print" to see the choice and it's normal i can see it in my terminal, but not in the page browser of my django application indeed ,i can see just the first choices **without considering what i have append in my views.py**,...
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list `extend` method. (Make sure your `CHOICES` is a `LIST`)

```py
new_choices[('abc', 'def'),]
CHOICES.extend(new_choices)
```

(Note: It will not override the existing value in select field, and will create another choice with same value)

Comment: Hi@Rajeel Rajput, the same, it's doesn't give me any result in my browser, i see the result just in the terminal, I do no but is there any other instruction or code i should add after append or extend new choices....

Comment: @maiteperroni did you make CHOICES variable before assigning dite variable in your models.py?

Comment: yeah for sure.       CHOICES = [
       ('US', 'Unit'),

    ]
   dite = models.CharField( null = True, max_length=60,choices = CHOICES)

Comment: sorry for the misleading, i just realized i told you to extend choices in models.py. the extend should be in forms.py.
If the problem still happens, please provide me screenshots of your forms.py, models.py, views.py. I will definitely look into what i can do more